# Javascript object function call wont work

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm working on a HTML5 soundboard, but i've hit a bit of a snag...

I'm trying to get a stop function to work on all of the sounds at once that are played. Unfortunatly when i call this function from a buttonpress, the object doesn't appear to have a stop function. The code for the actual sound element is the following:

```
// Container to keep all sounds in one place. This is a Dictionary within a dictionary to be able to search by catagory.
var sounds = {};

// Counter to keep track of unique ID's
var lastID = 0;


// Base class for initializing Any class
var Base = function(methods){
    var base = function() {    
        this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);          
    };  

    for (var property in methods) { 
       base.prototype[property] = methods[property];
    }

    if (!base.prototype.initialize) base.prototype.initialize = function(){};      

    return base;    
};

//Complete class for the Sound object. Generates its own DIV's and HTML5 tags to play stuff.
var Sound = Base({ 
    // Init all the variables. 
    initialize: function(name, file, target='Sounds') {
        this.name = name;
        this.file = file
        this.button = null;
        this.audioelement;
        this.id = lastID + 1;
        this.target = target;
        lastID ++;


        // Check if the catagory is there, if not: create it with a placeholder object
        var catagory = sounds[this.target];
        if(catagory == null){
            sounds[this.target] = {99:null};

        }
        sounds[this.target][this.id] = this;

        // Call init function
        this.init();
    },

    play : function() {
        obj = this
        if(obj.audioelement.paused == true){
            obj.audioelement.play();    
        }else{
            obj.audioelement.pause();
            obj.audioelement.fastSeek(0);
        }

    },
    stop : function(){
        obj = this;
        obj.audioelement.pause();
    },
    init : function(){

        // Statement for JS class based shenanigans.
        obj = this

        // Create a button and add some text to it
        obj.button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        obj.button.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj.name));

        // Set ID's and names to keep track of this button
        obj.button.id = obj.id;
        obj.button.name = obj.target;

        // Get or create parent element. Used for catagory based display
        var el = getOrCreateElement(obj.target)
        el.appendChild(obj.button);

        // Create audio element and set appropriate settings
        obj.audioelement = document.createElement("AUDIO");
        obj.audioelement.src = obj.file;
        obj.audioelement.name
        obj.button.appendChild(obj.audioelement);

        // Add function to play/pause to button
        obj.button.onclick = buttonClicked;

});
function buttonClicked(){
    // Fetch sound from dicionary container using the name and id from the button [SET AT SOUND.INIT()]
    var sound = sounds[this.name][this.id];
    // Call the play function in [SOUND]
    sound.play();
}
```

And for the stopall function:

```
function stopAll(){
    // Scroll through the entire dictionary
    for ( var key in sounds){
        for ( var id in sounds[key]){
            // Check if the sound is not a placeholder
            if(id == 99){
                continue;
            }
            // Call stop function with fetched object.
            var sound = sounds[key][id];
            sound.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

The weird thing is is that the play function does seem to work, but not the stop function. It says that the object doesn't have that specific function...

Any ideas would be appriciated!

WM

Comment: you should post the code you are using to do play/stop as well if you want some help.

Comment: The actual functions are all there. The only thing that is missing is the logic to call the functions itself. I'll add the functions that do that

Comment: Do you have any error message?

Answer (score 0):

`for ( var x in object)` loops over a few more properties than just methods, including ones on the base object's prototype.

If you `console.log(id);` within that inner loop you will see the extra ones.

Try adding this inside your inner for loop:

```
if (typeof id !== 'function') {
    continue;
}
```

Edit: this isn't quite correct but I'm not in a position to see what it should be right now. It's almost there, from memory! Keep playing with it.

Comment: This is true only by non-ES5 environments, so in very old browsers.

Comment: Hmm, maybe 7 years ago. :D